# Using flask to get the details of a system visiting my website

Tags: python, flask, subprocess

I have built a website using flask (Python 2.7). I am trying to send a setup file to a system visiting my website according to the specifications of that system. Thus I want to access the cmd prompt of that system and find few things: 
1. which os and bit that pc is working on 
2. does it have python installed.

Till now I was using local host so things seemed fine with my code.

(This one is to detect the os of the system)

```
def index():
    var3 = subprocess.call('uname -o > z2.txt' , shell = True)
    if (var3 == 0):
        return render_template("ch1.html") #ch1 says its ubuntu
    else :
        return render_template("ch2.html") #ch2 says its windows
```

I had previously checked on other windows pc and it had displayed windows which made me think my code was fine. Now when i am checking on ubuntu it still shows windows. Now i realize that the subprocess.call calls the commands on my system's cmd itself and not on the system visiting my website. 
How can i access the visiting system's cmd to find their os, bit and whether python is installed on their system using PYTHON/Flask.

NOTE: All of the systems visiting my website will be connected to the same wifi (if that is of any help)

EDIT: Getting the os, bit and python installed or not on the visitor's system from my website is my main criteria. It can be by accessing the other system's cmd or in any other way possible.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. Why do you care? Most likely there is a better way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to send a setup file according to the specifications of the client system from my website (which is made using flask) to the client system. Thus I care about the specifications. A better way how? Please, any help will be really helpful.

Comment: You probably need to create a single install package per OS you support, and just have the installer (which will run on the client system) figure out what needs to be done to install your system. Or perhaps you should just build your app as an OS native package, and bundle your runtime dependencies like Python inside your installer, if that works for you legally.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way you can execute commands on a client machine from a web server. Otherwise it would be a major security problem.

You can only know client's OS name by read its user-agent information through the Flask request object: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.13/utils/#module-werkzeug.useragents

Comment: Thanks. I edited that part of accessing cmd. This link will give me the os. Can you please suggest a way to get the bit version and whether system has python installed.

Comment: I'm afraid that you can't access those information.

Comment: Note that you can't even **know** the client OS by parsing the `User-Agent` header, because you have no way to know whether the client is telling the truth. It's easy to send whatever headers you like with e.g. `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check client's OS from HTTP requests but that's about it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent